# Error in accessing the date in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtstart.Text, "yyyyMMdd", null);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtend.Text, "yyyyMMdd", null);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "select * from Membership_det where updateDate  between "+ 
      startDate.ToString() + " and "+ endDate.ToString() +" ", con);
```

It gives error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.When date is entered in
>   mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: You should **always** use **parametrized queries** and pass in your parameters as `DateTime` to avoid fiddling around with dates in string format!

Answer (score 1):

Well yes - you're explicitly specifying that you want to parse it in `yyyyMMdd` format. I don't see why you'd *expect* it to work if you've actually specified it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. If you want to handle that instead, change your parsing code:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtstart.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtend.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However:

- If this is parsing user input, you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead, so you can detect errors in the input in the normal flow instead of using exceptions.
- This code is very US-centric; non-US users may well find it confusing. In general you'd *either* be better off using one of the standard date formats (and the user's culture) *or* even better, using a date picker control of some form, to avoid the whole text format issue to start with.

Next you're using the values directly in the SQL statement. **Don't do that.** Always, always, always use parameterized SQL:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "select * from Membership_det where updateDate  between @Start and @End",
    con);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate;
```

(Or create the command first and then pass that to the adapter.)

Using parameterized SQL has three benefits:

- It avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- It avoids data conversion issues (which are common with dates)
- It keeps your SQL easy to read by separating the code from the data

Comment: Just in  case i want to know...is there any use of  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture...?in the code..?\

Comment: @user2660112: When you specify a custom date format, you should almost always specify the culture explicitly too. You're effectively specifying a US-centric date format, so it makes sense to treat all of it as US-centric.

Answer (score 0):

Access DB Only

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtstart.Text, "MMddyyyy", null);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtend.Text, "MMddyyyy", null);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "select * from Membership_det where format( updateDate,'MM/dd/yyyy')  between '"+ 
      startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and '"+ endDate.Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy") +"' ", con);
```

Sql Server

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtstart.Text, "MMddyyyy", null);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtend.Text, "MMddyyyy", null);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "select * from Membership_det where Convert(varchar(15), updateDate,106)  between '"+ 
      startDate.ToString(dd MMM yyyy) + "' and '"+ endDate.Tostring(dd MMM yyyy) +"' ", con);
```